# android:style not applying in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, android-theme, android-styles

I need to apply a custom style to a Spinner.

These are my styles in styles.xml:

```
<style name="spinnerItemStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/small_text</item>
</style>

<style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/small_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/unpressed2</item>
</style>
```

And I'm doing this in the layout:

> android:spinnerItemStyle="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
>   android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/songSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
            android:entries="@array/songs_array"
            android:spinnerItemStyle="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
            android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.18"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/musicSeekBar"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />
```

The problem is that Spinner is ignoring the styles applied.

And also I disscovered that it works perfectly if I do this in my custom app theme inside styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/unpressed2</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font</item>

    <!-- spinner styles -->
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
        @style/spinnerItemStyle
    </item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
    </item>
</style>
```

Why works with my second approach and not with the first?

Comment: `android:spinnerItemStyle` and `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` are attributes defined at **theme level**. It doesn't mean that you can use  `android:spinnerItemStyle` in your `View`. You can define something like `<style name="CustomSpinner" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerItemStyle</item>
<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>
 </style>` and then use in your `Spinner` layout the `android:theme="@style/CustomSpinner"` attribute

Answer (score 1):

**styles.xml File**

> Add below xml code in your styles.xml File.

```
<style name="CustomSpinner" parent="AppTheme">

     <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerItemStyle</item> 
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle</item> 

</style>
```

**yourlayout.xml**

> In Spinner use this styles

For E.g:-

```
<Spinner
       android:id="@+id/songSpinner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/CustomSpinner">
  </Spinner>
```

Comment: Just to copy my comment.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sir Please put your answer in systematically, Many user can not understand comment answer, So  that i put answer in systematically .